# apache subversion how to remove user access

Tags: svn

Once a while ago I installed apache subversion onto an Ubuntu machine. Then, one of my colleagues took control of it. Recently he quit his job and now i have to remove his user in order to prevent future accesses.

I have read many posts and google a lot. Under conf folder (in each repository), there are authz, passwd, and svnserve files but there is no user in these files, I have checked whether anonymous access is enabled or not and realized that users cannot access anonymously.

I have checked users that have access to repositories with the following command:

```
svn log -q file:///var/subversion | grep -e '^r' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|" } ; { print $2 }' | sort | uniq
```

and I can see the user name in the output. I also checked Linux user with

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

command and the user is not in the list. I also checked http.conf file under /etc/apache2 which is empty and dav_svn.passwd file which only contains my test user.

What I am trying to do is to remove this specific user. Is there any hint for how I can do that?

ps: I believe old commits of this user won't be lost after deletion. Is that right?

Answer (score 3):

In assumption, that `AuthType Basic` was used (in case of Digest command have to be changed to htdigest and options re-checked) **correct way** have to be (according to [htpasswd doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html))

- deleting user: `htpasswd -D PASSWDFILE username`
- replacing passwords (lazy dirty solution without scripting, handwork, may be improved):

`htpasswd -b PASSWDFILE username password` (password in plain-text in command) for each username

Comment: Thank you Lazy Badger.. I was trying the command yesterday. If I use the same password file with the user_name, it asks to `update` the password and then updates the password in md5 format. If I enter a new user, it asks for a `new` password and adds the user to the password file.

Answer (score 1):

O.K. I got the answer. The path for the file used for passwords is given in the file `dav_svn.conf` which is under `/etc/apache2/modes_available`. When I check the path, all the users and passwords were present in the file.

I have put a dollar sign before the user I want to prevent, restarted apache, and problem solved.

The other problem now is, since that person created all accounts, he also knows other usernames and their passwords. I want to change the passwords for all users, however, they are all encrypted. How can I change the user passwords? Should I delete them all and add back again?